# Grails 3 spring.Security override Register form

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am new to grails and trying to use `Spring.security.ui` plugin. I used  grails `s2ui-override` auth to override login form and added link to register form. I can redirect to standard plugin register from, however I would like to customize this register form.

When I run grails s2ui-override register register, i get this error:

```
 Copying register resources | Rendered template RegisterController.groovy.template to destination grails-app/controllers/register/RegisterController.groovy
| Error Command [s2ui-override] error: class path resource [layouts/register.gsp] cannot be opened because it does not exist (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved it by simply coping code from spring security ui plugin for grails 3 from Github repo to my project.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, it is a bit of a pain, but you need to actually copy this file

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/views/layouts/register.gsp

Into the directory **grails-app/register/layouts/**