# Grails3 -spring security ui, s2ui-override can't find register.gsp

Tags: spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm trying to change the registration page in Spring security to not require email confirmation, so I was trying to make this change, and ran into this error:

Command [s2ui-override] error: class path resource [layouts/register.gsp] cannot be opened because it does not exist (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

I then created a empty file in layouts/register.gsp just to see if that would help but it did not.

I looked in the plugin bundle to see if I could find the gsp, but it wasn't there.  It seems like the gsp is created programitically, but I'm too much of a newbie to figure out how to do that.  I was hoping to look at hte GSP to get a sense of how the controller actually works, since s2UI generates only an extended version of the controller, which is also tedious if you have ot figure out how it works to change its behavior. (Yes, I looked at hte documentation for Grails spring security plugin but the core documentation seems pretty opaque.)

Anyway, if anybody knows how to get handle this error, much appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760896/grails-3-spring-security-override-register-form/44792472#44792472