# Grails, spring-security I want to register new users without need of email-confirmation

Tags: spring, authentication, grails

Registration is made by an admin and email-confirmation is not needed/wanted.

I have used the overide-script but it just creates an empty controller and I have no idea how to use it.
it looks like this:

```
package com.myProj.security

class RegisterController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {
}
```

Running the command also give me this answer:

```
| Copying register resources
| Rendered template RegisterController.groovy.template to destination grails-app\controllers\com\testx\ui\RegisterController.groovy
| Error Command [s2ui-override] error: class path resource [layouts/register.gsp] cannot be opened because it does not exist (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [layouts/register.gsp] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.grails.io.support.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:148)
        at org.grails.io.support.SpringIOUtils.copy(SpringIOUtils.java:196)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.io.FileSystemInteractionImpl.copy(FileSystemInteractionImpl.groovy:144)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.io.FileSystemInteractionImpl.copy(FileSystemInteractionImpl.groovy)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.script.GroovyScriptCommand.copy(GroovyScriptCommand.groovy:58)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.io.FileSystemInteraction$copy$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at s2ui-override.copy(s2ui-override.groovy:113)
        at s2ui-override.run(s2ui-override.groovy:108)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.script.GroovyScriptCommand.handle(GroovyScriptCommand.groovy:152)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:481)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:377)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:350)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:271)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
```

Any idea how to proceed? The manuals have not helped me. Maybe I miss something there?

==============================================

I found some code at GitHub and copied some lines from the RegisterController and added it to my almost empty RegisterController.

```
package com.myProj.security
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.dao.NullSaltSource
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.MailStrategy
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.PropertiesStrategy
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.RegistrationCodeStrategy
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.SaltSource
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class RegisterController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {
    def register(RegisterCommand registerCommand) {

        if (!request.post) {
            return [registerCommand: new RegisterCommand()]
        }

        if (registerCommand.hasErrors()) {
            return [registerCommand: registerCommand]
        }

        def user = uiRegistrationCodeStrategy.createUser(registerCommand)
        String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null : registerCommand.username
        RegistrationCode registrationCode = uiRegistrationCodeStrategy.register(user, registerCommand.password, salt)

        if (registrationCode == null || registrationCode.hasErrors()) {
            // null means problem creating the user
            flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.register.miscError')
            return [registerCommand: registerCommand]
        }

        user = uiRegistrationCodeStrategy.finishRegistration(registrationCode)

        if (!user) {
            flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.register.badCode')
            redirect uri: successHandlerDefaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        if (user.hasErrors()) {
            // expected to be handled already by ErrorsStrategy.handleValidationErrors
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.register.complete')
        redirect uri: registerPostRegisterUrl ?: successHandlerDefaultTargetUrl
    }
}
```

Theres no suprice to me that it don't work but I wonder how the authors want me to do to make it work. The imports doesn't look to be reachable so the the code wont compile. And even if it could, how can I ensure this controller to be called?

Comment: Are you using spring security UI? https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/v3/index.html#userRegistration Or just the core spring security stuff? Personally I don't use spring security UI & just have a simple hand written controller & gsp that accepts username etc & passes work off to ldapUserDetailsManager, I can show this if need be

Comment: Yes, I do. There is a lot more of things that don't work as expected when running the s2ui-override script. The only gsp I could get is auth.gsp.

Comment: Did you run `grails s2ui-override register`? which should 'copy the registration controller and GSPs into your application to be customized' as per section 5.4 of linked doc

Comment: Well, if you look at the errormessage from the command "s2ui-override register, shown in the question, you can see that it claims that the file can not be found (layouts/register.gsp).

Comment: Hmmm, maybe delete the RegisterController & try again with `--stacktrace`, I'm not sure how much you'll get in register.gsp after it's been created, it may be empty, you could even create /templates/register.gsp & rerun & see if it fills out

Comment: I tried that but the result is exactly the same. I also tried on another simple test project and it is the same problem there too. I don't know from where it copies these files. In the error print it says from layouts/register.gsp so to me it likes it tries to copy from the common dir where the main.gsp is stored.

Comment: If i put a file named register.gsp in /templates it will be that file you get when linking to /register. But that's weak help when I don't know how to buildd the controller but maybe the code can be fetched on GITHUB?

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760896/grails-3-spring-security-override-register-form

Comment: I have already tried that and copied some code from the ui-project but I can't find out how I should make it to call my version of the controller. I found som instructions to setup urlmapping for it but no result.